# Opportunity Record Type Selection Page

Tags: visualforce, controller, custom-controller

I'm trying to create a visualforce page which clones the record type selection page when creating new Opportunities. I'd like the page to display opp record types based on the related account record type. Below is the code but I'm getting error this error:

> Variable does not exist:currentAccount.RecordType.DeveloperName

```
public class myController {

    public List<SelectOption> opts             {get;set;}
    private String oType                        {get;set;}
    public Id recTypeId                         {get;set;}

    myController(){
        oType = 'Opportunity';
    }

    public List<SelectOption> myOptions() {
        opts = new List<SelectOption>();

        opts.add(new SelectOption('','--Please Select Record Type --'));

        for(RecordType rts : [Select Id, DeveloperName, Name From RecordType Where SObjectType = 'Opportunity']) {
        opts.add(new SelectOption(rts.id,rts.name));
        }

            Map<String,List<String>> mapping = new Map<String,List<String>>();
            mapping.put('Small_Medium_Sized_Business', new List<String>{'Defined_Benefit_Retirement','Defined_Contribution_Retirement'});


        return opts;
    }
}
```

**Edit** to add Visual Force Page Code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account"> 
   <apex:form > 
      <apex:selectList value="{!recTypeID}" size="1"> 
         <apex:selectOptions value="{!myOptions}">
         </apex:selectOptions> 
      </apex:selectList> 
      <apex:commandButton value="Next" Action="{!continue}"/> 
   </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Can someone help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Where are your getters and setters in the controller? I see no references to `currentAccount.RecordType.DeveloperName` except in your 2nd query. Your controller hasn't built this map and it's not done a `get` of the Account ID's or `Opportunity.Account` needed to build it.

You have a `return options` statement, but what are you returning those options to? How are you planning to get them back to your VF page?

Once you do that, I'm assuming you'll need to get your selection(s) back to your controller for cloning which you'll need to add another method for.

I highly recommend you take a look at the [VisualForce Workbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_vf.meta/workbook_vf/workbook_vf_intro.htm), the [VisualForce Developer's Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_intro.htm) and the [Force.com Apex Code Developer's Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_intro_chapter.htm) for more on VisualForce pages and custom controllers.

**Edit** in response to comments...

In your VisualForce page,

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
```

The above should refer to your custom controller and look something more like this:

```
<apex:page Controller="myController">
```

Error: Unknown property `AccountStandardController.recTypeID` is in part because you're specifying the wrong controller. Once you do have the correct controller, I suspect you'll still see errors because what you're returning and "setting" is not the recordtype.ID. Your controller as written above, appears to "return" or set "opts" which you have listed in your page as `!myOptions` which doesn't appear to me to be what you're setting.

Again, I highly recommend you take a look at the VF Workbook and other references I pointed you to which might help get you quickly sorted if you'll only spend a few minutes with them.

Comment: Thanks! Here's the new code I've got but I get this error when saving my VF page:   Error: Unknown property 'AccountStandardController.recTypeID'

Comment: Here's my VF code:<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:form >
            <apex:selectList value="{!recTypeID}" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!myOptions}"></apex:selectOptions>
            </apex:selectList>          
    <apex:commandButton value="Next" Action="{!continue}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>

Comment: See my revised answer